# Unable to download snapshot in KVM through GUI

Tags: virtualization, redhat, kvm-virtualization, rhev

I am using KVM in GUI mode and I have created a snapshot for one of the server and I want to export that in HyperV. To do that I want to extract it to my desktop to convert the snapshot into vhdx format. Where can I found the snapshot to download it to my PC?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJSgh.png)

Answer (score 0):

RHEV provides a way to export the VM's snapshot to an export domain, you can get the image from there.